# react storybook load csv file

Tags: reactjs, csv, storybook

I have a quick question regarding how to load a static file in React storybook framework. Currently, I created a storybook by following the instruction in [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#getting-started-with-storybook).

Now, I am trying to load a csv file containing some data to visualize. For this, I placed the csv file under public folder by following the instruction [here](https://storybook.js.org/configurations/serving-static-files/).

However, I couldn't load the file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default webpack config storybook provides would not allow importing csv files; it only supports media files like images in the example.

What you'll want to do is add this custom loader, [dsv-loader](https://github.com/wbkd/dsv-loader), to your storybook webpack config using [Extend Mode](https://storybook.js.org/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#extend-mode). You will then be able to import the csv data as a javascript object.